# How to extract data from a file to be used as variables in C

Tags: c

In this piece of code im getting value of row and column from the user.
But instead I wanted to know if i could extract these data from a file rather than manking the user input them.
Is there any way to do that?

Can you please help me guys im very new to his language, and im not even sure if we could do that

file format(5 is for rows and 4 is for columns):

```
5,4
```

```
 printf("Please enter the number of rows that you would like to play on:");
 scanf("%d", &row);

 while (row < 3 || row >10)
 {
     fputs("Error, input a valid number: ", stderr);
     scanf("%d", &row);
 }

 printf("please enter the number of columns that you would like to play on:");
 scanf("%d", &col);

 while (col < 3 || col > 10) 
 {
     fputs("Error, input a valid number: ", stderr);
     scanf("%d", &col);
 }
```

Comment: Does this even compile? Please also check the return value from `scanf`

Comment: @EdHeal  No, My issue here is how to extract these values from a file instead of making the user input it. I wont be using these code afterwards

Comment: Read about file I/O and fopen, fscanf, etc.

Comment: Why not make the code fault tolerant?

Comment: Yes, but why complicate things? Using the OS redirection from `stdin` is often a superior method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `fscanf` function works much like the `scanf` function, but allows input from a `FILE`.  The `FILE` must first be opened with `fopen` I recommend checking that the `FILE` is non-null and `fscanf` returns non-End-Of-File so you don't have undefined behaviour if the file is missing or invalid. See for example, the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
   FILE *fp;
   int row, col;
   fp = fopen("file.txt", "r"); /* open for "r"eading */
   if (fp) {
       if (fscanf(fp, "%d,%d", &row, &col)==2) {
           printf("%d:%d", row, col );
       }
   }
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `EOF` should be 2, and `!=` should be `==`

Comment: I see, the !=EOF would have allowed col to be undefined. Missed that. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the contents of a file using a `FILE` pointer.
The address is set using `fopen()` where the first argument is a `char*` for the file name and the second is a `char*` for permissions (e.g. read, write, read and write, etc.).

If you can assume that the contents of the file are valid, you can open and read two numbers from a file as follows:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("filename", "r");

if(fscanf(fp, "%d,%d", &row, &col) != 2)) {
    //handle error
    printf("error\n");
}

fclose(fp);
```

Though I would still strongly recommend validating these anyways, as well as checking that the file contains all the required data before attempting to read it.

Comment: Shouldn't `%d%d` be `%d,%d`?

Comment: And check the return value from `fcanf`

Comment: Thanks @marco-a, not sure how I missed that, my bad

Comment: @EdHeal Thanks for the suggestion, I've added a basic check, though I would suggest that OP handles the error as is appropriate for his use case.

Answer (score 0):

sure,the C standard library have a file system you can

Here a example on Writing and Reading to a file.

```
int main(void)
{
  FILE *fp;
  char buff[255];

  fp = fopen("/myfolder/myfile.txt", "w+"); /*the w+ makes the file read and write*/
  fprintf(fp, "This text is saved in the file\n");
  fputs("This is another method\n", fp);

  fscanf(fp, "%s", buff);
  printf("%s\n", buff );

  fgets(buff, 255, (FILE*)fp);
  printf("%s\n", buff );

  fclose(fp);
}
```